# grep by row and column using bash

Tags: regex, bash, csv, awk, grep

Assuming the following sample csv input

> SYMBOL,JAN-11     ,FEB-11     ,MAR-11
>   DEF   ,20         ,25         ,20
>   HIG   ,50         ,50         ,50

Is there anyway to grep for a particular value using both row and column
i.e. grep for symbol DEF and FEB-11 should return value 25

The row-wise grep is trivial but i am having problems with the column wise grep. 
any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: grep is completely the wrong tool. Try awk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams said, `awk` is a much better tool for this job. Try the following script:

```
#!/bin/awk -f

# usage: csvgrep row column [file]

BEGIN {
    FS = "[ \t]*,[ \t]"
    row = ARGV[1]
    col = ARGV[2]
    ARGV[1] = ARGV[2] = ""

    # read header
    getline
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
        if ($i == col) {
            col = i
            break
        }
}

($1 == row) { print $col }
```

You may want to add input validation. `awk` may be in `/usr/bin` on your system.

Comment: +1 You could easily make this into an AWK script without the shell wrapper.

Comment: some improvements: use `match($i, col)` and `match($1,row)` instead of `$i==col` and `$1==row` to allow regular expressions instead of exact matching; after reading the header, check the value of `col` to ensure that the desired header column has been found.